# WP_JSON prepare data for mobile app, wrong format

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to export data from my website using wp-json rest api.
This data should be read in a precise format by an app, but I can't find the way to provide correct structure.

**Desidered format**

The Events should be group by `group` category, each event should got a `time` parameter and in `sessions` I will store the event.
Here is how should like:

```
{
  "schedule": [
    {
      "date": "2047-05-17",
      "groups": [
        {
          "time": "26 July 2020",
          "sessions": [
            {
              "name": "Getting Started with Ionic",
              "location": "Hall 2",
              "description": "Mobile devices and browsers are now advanced enough that developers can build native-quality mobile apps using open web technologies like HTML5, Javascript, and CSS. In this talk, we’ll provide background on why and how we created Ionic, the design decisions made as we integrated Ionic with Angular, and the performance considerations for mobile platforms that our team had to overcome. We’ll also review new and upcoming Ionic features, and talk about the hidden powers and benefits of combining mobile app development and Angular.",
              "speakerNames": [
                "Ted Turtle"
              ],
              "timeStart": "9:30 am",
              "timeEnd": "9:45 am",
              "tracks": [
                "Concerti"
              ],
              "id": "2",
              "pic": "madison.jpg"
            },
            {
              "name": "Ionic Tooling",
              "location": "Executive Ballroom",
              "description": "Mobile devices and browsers are now advanced enough that developers can build native-quality mobile apps using open web technologies like HTML5, Javascript, and CSS. In this talk, we’ll provide background on why and how we created Ionic, the design decisions made as we integrated Ionic with Angular, and the performance considerations for mobile platforms that our team had to overcome. We’ll also review new and upcoming Ionic features, and talk about the hidden powers and benefits of combining mobile app development and Angular.",
              "speakerNames": [
                "Rachel Rabbit"
              ],
              "timeStart": "9:45 am",
              "timeEnd": "10:00 am",
              "tracks": [
                "Tooling"
              ],
              "id": "3",
              "pic": "chicago.jpg"
            },
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "time": "30 July 2020",
          "sessions": [
            {
              {
              "name": "University of Ionic",
              "location": "Hall 3",
              "description": "Mobile devices and browsers are now advanced enough that developers can build native-quality mobile apps using open web technologies like HTML5, Javascript, and CSS. In this talk, we’ll provide background on why and how we created Ionic, the design decisions made as we integrated Ionic with Angular, and the performance considerations for mobile platforms that our team had to overcome. We’ll also review new and upcoming Ionic features, and talk about the hidden powers and benefits of combining mobile app development and Angular.",
              "speakerNames": [
                "Ellie Elephant"
              ],
              "timeStart": "9:15 am",
              "timeEnd": "9:30 am",
              "tracks": [
                "Ionic"
              ],
              "id": "4",
              "pic": "seattle.jpg"
            }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Actual Situation**

`sessions` should be wrapped into `groups`, at the time, these are different element of `schedule`.

```
{
   "schedule":[
      {
         "date":"2020-08-28",
         "groups":[
            {
               "time":"28 Aug 2020",
               "sessions":[
                  {
                     "name":"Getting Started with Ionic",
                     "location":"Hall 2",
                     "description":"Mobile devices and browsers are now advanced enough that developers can build native-quality mobile apps using open web technologies like HTML5, Javascript, and CSS. In this talk, we’ll provide background on why and how we created Ionic, the design decisions made as we integrated Ionic with Angular, and the performance considerations for mobile platforms that our team had to overcome. We’ll also review new and upcoming Ionic features, and talk about the hidden powers and benefits of combining mobile app development and Angular.",
                     "speakerNames": [
                        "Rachel Rabbit"
                     ],
                     "timeStart": "9:45 am",
                     "timeEnd": "10:00 am",
                     "tracks": [
                        "Tooling"
                     ],
                     "id": "3",
                     "pic": "chicago.jpg"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "date":"2020-08-29",
         "groups":[
            {
               "time":"29 Aug 2020",
               "sessions":[
                  {
                     "name":"Andy e Norman – Teatro Lyrick",
                     "location":"Santa Maria degli Angeli",
                     "description":"Il duo comico Gigi e Ross debutta a teatro con la commedia Andy e Norman, fiaba moderna del commediografo newyorkese Neil Simon, messa in scena con grande successo a Broadway nel 1966. La vicenda ruota attorno a due scapoli che dividono lo stesso appartamento e, con grandi difficoltà, dirigono e producono una rivista alternativa. Ad alterare il già precario equilibrio tra i due ci penserà Sophie, attraente ragazza americana trasferitasi da poco nell'abitazione accanto.",
                     "timeStart":"29 Aug 2020 09:48",
                     "timeEnd":"29 Aug 2020 09:48",
                     "tracks":[
                        "Teatro"
                     ],
                     "id":5542,
                     "pic":"https://www.eventiassisi.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/225418127-61acfbf1-6fc4-45e0-b43c-1eb92d292776.webp"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "date":"2020-10-31",
         "groups":[
            {
               "time":"31 Oct 2020",
               "sessions":[
                  {
                     "name":"Pink Sonic – Assisi",
                     "location":"Santa Maria degli Angeli",
                     "description":"",
                     "timeStart":"31 Oct 2020 11:37",
                     "timeEnd":"31 Oct 2020 11:00",
                     "tracks":[
                        "Concerti"
                     ],
                     "id":5626,
                     "pic":"https://www.eventiassisi.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/pink-sonic.jpg"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Actual Code**

```
function app_get_newer_posts($data) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'paged' => $data['page']
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $ret = [];

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $term = get_term(get_the_ID,'');
            $query->the_post();
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ita', 'it_IT');
            if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0] < date("Y-m-d")) {
                $ret['schedule'][] = [
                    'date' => date('Y-m-d',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]),
                    'groups' => [[
                        'time' => utf8_encode( strftime("%d %b %Y", get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]) ),
                        'sessions' => [[
                            'name' => html_entity_decode(the_title('','',false), ENT_QUOTES),
                            'location' => get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location')[0]->name,
                            'description' => get_the_content(),
                            'timeStart' => date('d M Y h:i',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_start_time')[0]),
                            'timeEnd' => date('d M Y h:i',get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'ovaem_date_end_time')[0]),
                            'tracks' => [ get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'categorie' )[0]->name ],
                            'id' => get_the_ID(),
                            'pic' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
                        ]]
                    ]]
                ];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Data are correctly returned but in an incorrect format, hope someone can help

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you need help with  - is it just the date format, or the structure of the JSON (or both)? If its the format, can you let us know what the criteria for the JSON is - for example, the "desired format" shows all the sessions on the same date, but the sessions in your data are on different dates. What is the desired output when you have multiple dates? If you could edit your question to show us that, we can look at how to do that for you :)

Comment: Thanks you for your reply @FluffyKitten. Sorry if I've been not so clear. Problem is on the format, don't care about `date` on `schedule`, it's a grouping used by the app, the only date value I'm really using is under `time`. What I need is group data under `"groups" : [{ "date" : "xyz", "sessions" : { ITEM1 }, "date": "zxy", "sessions" : { ITEM 2 } etc`.

Comment: You haven't explained what is wrong with the result in your "actual situation"...  the event dates are different so they wouldn't be grouped together anyway? The content & dates in the actual output are different from the desired output, so we can't compare them to see what you are looking for, and you have only explained what you want when the dates are the same, so it's really difficult to work out what exactly you are expecting when dates are different. Please edit your question to give more details so we can help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've update the OP, trying to explain how the structure should be

Comment: It still doesn't tell us what you expect when the dates are different or your "Actual Situation" should look like.

Comment: @FluffyKitten as you can see, events should be group by `time` leaving `date` as supergroup untouched, I don't need it, it could be leaved as 2047-05-17 (That's why the app treat it as a filter, events will be displayed untill that date has passed). Now they're grouped by `date`, this let the app reading for just one item in the json structure. I don't know how to be more clear. Sorry If it's not so easy to understand.

Comment: As I've asked before, please show us *exactly* what the desired output for your "Actual Situation" is. The "desired situation" here does not have the same details as your actual output.

Comment: @FluffyKitten The content is example text, the keys are the same. What I should need is to change the output structure (so just the keys) in second example in the structure you can see in first example.